# Add class to div when in viewport

Tags: jquery, function, viewport

I want to add a class to a menu item when a different div enters the viewport.

I have successfully replicated the alert found here: http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/M2RzU/ However, when I try to change it from an alert to an addClass or toggleClass it breaks. This is my code:

```
$('#portfolio').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible == true) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
    $( "#menu-item-portfolio" ).addClass( ".active-area" );
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
  }
});`
```

I want to add .active-area to #menu-item-portfolio when #portfolio enters the viewport, then remove it when #portfolio leaves the viewport.

Comment: at which element you want to add and remove the class.

Comment: I want to add .active-area to #menu-item-portfolio when #portfolio enters the viewport, then remove it when #portfolio leaves the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger the event `inview` on document ready.

```
$('.myclass').trigger('inview');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2RzU/26/)**

View the changes in console in fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. There was a typo in the code. Instead of
    .addClass(".active-area")
it should be 
    .addClass("active-area")

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.myclass').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible == true) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
   $("h2").removeClass('myclass');
      alert('found h2!')
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
     $("h2").addClass('myclass');
  }
});
});
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/M2RzU/24/