# Link div sections to navigation buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page which has 5 panels in different colors. And there is navigation bullet on right side of the page.

When scrolling the page I want each section to linked with the navigation bullets. Bullet should have `active` class based on which slide is shown on the viewport.

Any help would be appreciated.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p1bshcL4/4/)**

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214810/add-class-to-div-when-in-viewport

Comment: try to use javascript

Comment: use this reference https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your code in my local and applied below JS and after that its working fine.

**Just add [Scrollit.Js](http://www.bytemuse.com/scrollIt.js/) in your project.**

Just you have to do minor changes in your CSS file like below.

In your CSS file line no. #55

```
.parallax_nav a:active,
.parallax_nav a:focus,
.parallax_nav a.js--active {
    background: #f5f5f1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

just replaxe it with

```
.parallax_nav a:active,
.parallax_nav a:focus,
.parallax_nav a.active {
    background: #f5f5f1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It will be working fine like as you want. Per section it will be apply active class on your `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes to your code to scroll to the div on click. For onscroll highlight, use scrollspy.js or go with bootstrap navigation. 
I personally recommend you to use bootstrap.

```
<body class="page-loaded">

<div id="page" class="hfeed site full-height">
    <div class="page-wrap full-height">

        <div class="main full-height" role="main">
            <div id="" class="content full-height">

                <div class="parallax_boxs">
                    <div id="black" class="parallax_box">
                        <div class="parallax_box_inner parallax_box_inner_box1">

                            <div class="parallax_box_clip">
                                <div class="parallax_box_phone">
                                    <div class="mobile_responsive">
                                        <div class="mobile_responsive_inner">
                                            <div class="mobile_responsive_bg">
                                                <div class="responsive_bg_wrap" data-reveal-bg="1">
                                                    <img alt="" aria-hidden="true" width="377" height="787" src="images/phone.png">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mobile_reveal">
                                                <div class="mobile_reveal_wrap" data-reveal-wrap="1">
                                                    <video loop="" autoplay="" id="video--1" poster="/assets/video/quizup-poster.jpg">
                                                        <source src="video/boostyourearnings.mov" type="video/mp4">
                                                    </video>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="wrap">
                                <div class="parallax_box__content" style="opacity: 1;">
                                    <div class="pbox_left">
                                            fhffdhfd
                                    </div>
                                 <div class="pbox_right">
                                        <h3>rehr</h3>
                                        <p>fshrsh <a target="_blank" class="link--invisible" href="https://fueled.com/android-app-design">Android app</a>.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="green" class="parallax_box ">
                        <div class="parallax_box_inner parallax_box_inner_box2">

                            <div class="parallax_box_clip">
                                <div class="parallax_box_phone">
                                    <div class="mobile_responsive">
                                        <div class="mobile_responsive_inner">
                                            <div class="mobile_responsive_bg">
                                                <div class="responsive_bg_wrap" data-reveal-bg="2">
                                                    <img alt="" aria-hidden="true" width="377" height="787" src="images/phone.png">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mobile_reveal">
                                                <div class="mobile_reveal_wrap" data-reveal-wrap="2">
                                                    <video loop="" autoplay="" id="video--2" poster="/assets/video/sunnycomb-poster.jpg">
                                                        <source src="video/engageyourfanbase.mov" type="video/mp4">
                                                    </video>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="wrap">
                                <div class="parallax_box__content" style="opacity: 1;">
                                    <div class="pbox_left">
                                        xvdshdsh
                                    </div>
                <div class="pbox_right">
                                        <h3>resheh</h3>
                                        <p>rehrh</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="blue" class="parallax_box ">
                        <div class="parallax_box_inner parallax_box_inner_box3">

                            <div class="parallax_box_clip">
                                <div class="parallax_box_phone">
                                    <div class="mobile_responsive">
                                        <div class="mobile_responsive_inner">
                                            <div class="mobile_responsive_bg">
                                                <div class="responsive_bg_wrap" data-reveal-bg="3">
                                                    <img alt="" aria-hidden="true" width="377" height="787" src="images/phone.png">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mobile_reveal">
                                                <div class="mobile_reveal_wrap" data-reveal-wrap="3">
                                                    <video loop="" autoplay="" id="video--3" poster="/assets/video/afterlight-poster.jpg">
                                                        <source src="video/showcaseyourvideosfirst.mov" type="video/mp4">
                                                    </video>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="wrap">
                                <div class="parallax_box__content" style="opacity: 1;">
                                    <div class="pbox_left">
                                            sgagash
                                    </div>
                                 <div class="pbox_right">
                                        <h3>Trhr</h3>
                                        <p>shsh</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div id="grey" class="parallax_box ">
                        <div class="parallax_box_inner parallax_box_inner_box4">

                            <div class="parallax_box_clip">
                                <div class="parallax_box_phone">
                                    <div class="mobile_responsive">
                                        <div class="mobile_responsive_inner">
                                            <div class="mobile_responsive_bg">
                                                <div class="responsive_bg_wrap" data-reveal-bg="4">
                                                    <img alt="" aria-hidden="true" width="377" height="787" src="images/phone.png">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mobile_reveal">
                                                <div class="mobile_reveal_wrap" data-reveal-wrap="4">
                                                    <video loop="" autoplay="" id="video--4" poster="/assets/video/keyme-poster.jpg">
                                                        <source src="video/trackwhatyouredoing.mov" type="video/mp4">
                                                    </video>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="wrap">
                                <div class="parallax_box__content" style="opacity: 1;">
                                    <div class="pbox_left">
                                        eaheheh
                                    </div>
                                 <div class="pbox_right">
                                        <h3>shdh</h3>
                                        <p>srehrh</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div id="red" class="parallax_box ">
                        <div class="parallax_box_inner parallax_box_inner_box5">

                            <div class="parallax_box_clip">
                                <div class="parallax_box_phone">
                                    <div class="mobile_responsive">
                                        <div class="mobile_responsive_inner">
                                            <div class="mobile_responsive_bg">
                                                <div class="responsive_bg_wrap" data-reveal-bg="5">
                                                    <img alt="" aria-hidden="true" width="377" height="787" src="images/phone.png">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mobile_reveal">
                                                <div class="mobile_reveal_wrap" data-reveal-wrap="5">
                                                    <video loop="" autoplay="" id="video--5" poster="/assets/video/athlete-minder-poster.jpg">
                                                        <source src="video/youcalltheshots.mov" type="video/mp4">
                                                    </video>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="wrap">
                                <div class="parallax_box__content" style="opacity: 1;">
                                    <div class="pbox_left">
                                        ehwhewhewh
                                    </div>
                                 <div class="pbox_right">
                                        <h3>Cdxhrhs</h3>
                                        <p>fdh</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>





                    <div class="parallax_nav">
                            <a id="black-btn" href="#black" class="js--active">Link</a>
                            <a id="green-btn" href="#green" >Link</a>
                            <a id="blue-btn" href="#blue" >Link</a>
                            <a id="grey-btn" href="#grey" >Link</a>
                            <a id="red-btn" href="#red" >Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> 
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#green-btn').on('click',function(){
   $('#green-btn').addClass("js--active");
   $('#black-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#blue-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#grey-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#red-btn').removeClass("js--active");
 });
 $('#black-btn').on('click',function(){
   $('#green-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#black-btn').addClass("js--active");
   $('#blue-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#grey-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#red-btn').removeClass("js--active");
 });
 $('#blue-btn').on('click',function(){
   $('#green-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#black-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#blue-btn').addClass("js--active");
   $('#grey-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#red-btn').removeClass("js--active");
 });
 $('#grey-btn').on('click',function(){
   $('#green-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#black-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#blue-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#grey-btn').addClass("js--active");
   $('#red-btn').removeClass("js--active");
 });
 $('#red-btn').on('click',function(){
   $('#green-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#black-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#blue-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#grey-btn').removeClass("js--active");
   $('#red-btn').addClass("js--active");
 });
});
```